# This scope, refers to window

Tags: javascript, scope, window, this

I am trying to understand one thing. I am given the function:
**Given code**

```
function initfunc() {
    var myVar= {
        name : "My name."
    };

    function display_it() {
        //console.log(this); //commented out, window
        alert(this.name);
    }
    document.onclick = myFunc(display_it, myVar);
}

initfunc();

function myFunc(display, x)
{
     //make it say My name.!
}
```

Now I am trying to make `display_it()` function, to display "My name." When I log `this` inside `display_it()` it refers to window object.

**My attempt**
The only 'bad idea' i got, was to put something like that inside `myFunc`:

```
function myFunc(display, x)
{
    window.name = context.name;
    func();
}
```

But i got the feeling there is better way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it by using `bind` and providing `myVar` as context. Also you need to return the function as you intend to use it as event handler

```
function myFunc(display, x) {
   return display.bind(x);
}
```

The first argument of `Function.bind` accepts an object which will be set as the context when the code executes.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: probably `return display.bind(x);` would be better as OP is trying to set an onclick, otherwise this is all going to happen immediately

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution.Don't know if it is helpful.

```
var init = {
  name : "myName",

  display  : function () {
         alert(name);      
    }
};

document.onclick = function() {
  init.display();
};
```

Live example: http://liveweave.com/ZWUwCu

Comment: I am unable to edit given code :( but thanks for trying!